# I18N translate "." or "%" causes a full array of ALL translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I am having an issue in my Rails app of translation using I18n. I create dynamic sentences in arrays like this `[:this_is_a, 5, :which_is_a_number, "."]` for which I translate each word one by one.

When I iterate through this and translate I18n.t(".") I get the full array of all translations in my entire app which outputs a 1000+ array text. This also seem to be true for I18n.t("%").

Is there a setting that stops this from happening? My only hack solution for this at the moment is to change all "." to " . " but I am hoping there is a better solution. Any advice?

Comment: How are you getting those tokens? Are you parsing a sentence and tokenizing or are you creating those groups in some other way?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by tokens but assume you mean the array items. Those are created dynamically as a result of a calculation. It could be [:this_is_a, "A", :which_is_a_letter, "!"] as well. So, the translations are pre-set but the strings are used differently. I do not wish to put the "." inside the translation for that reason, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"." is used for namespacing translation keys. If you have file like this:

```
module1:
  key_a: "Module1 Translation A"
  key_b: "Module1 Translation B"
module2:
  key_a: "Module2 Translation A"
```

Then you access those with "."

```
I18n.t("module1.key_a")
I18n.t("module2.key_a")
```

If you just use `I18n.t(".")` it will give whole top-level namespace. You can change this behavior by changing separator

```
I18n.t("module1@key_a", separator: "@")
```

Just choose some character that you know won't appear as token.

"%" character is used for interpolation:

```
module1:
  name: "My name is %{name}"
```

And then

```
I18n.t("module1.name", name: "John")
```

It doesn't look like you can change "%" to something else because it is hardcoded. But it should not return the whole array of translation. It should just return "translation missing" error. At least that is what I have on my version of I18n gem.

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems to work. In the end I realized I was able to bypass this in a very specialized way that was out of the scope of this question. For the sake of my question your answer was correct.